# Unicode emojis not displaying in browser but stored in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, emoji, utf8mb4

I'm attempting to display Emojis stored in my mysql database in the web browser and having issues. Initially the emoji's were being translated into

```
????
```

so did some research and have changed the charset of the desired table to utf8mb4. I am now able to store the unicodes in the database eg.

```
&#128564;
&#128155;
```

However when i retrieve the string via php that these are stored in, from the database i am only seeing the text around the codes and the codes themselves and not the emoji's. 
eg

```
"had a great weekend with the family &#128155;"
```

instead of:

"had a great weekend with the family 💛"

any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT

---

Solved my issue. I was using

```
htmlspecialcahrs()
```

on the input of the strings I want to store. This was converting the

```
&
```

to

```
&amp
```

causing the Emoji's not to be recognised as

```
&amp#128564
```

is not valid. I just had to remove the

```
htmlspecialchars
```

re-insert the strings and it worked!

Thanks for looking

Comment: You say that the database itself is utf8mb4 encoded, but what about the connection, file, PHP- and HTML-headers?

Comment: I think you had it right the first time but browsers don't have every single unicode character stored in them. To display them you might need to find a font that does have them in and send that to the user over the website

Comment: i've changed the font and this has made no difference. the issue is with interpreting the output from the database so is there one specific area I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not touch html entities such as `&#128155;`.  Something else is generating them.

If you are using json in php, check for a second arg to avoid htmlentities.

If you are stuck with the entities, you can turn them back into characters via `html_entity_decode()`.

It would be best to have utf8mb4 throughout; that is `UNHEX('F09F929B')` in the database, no use of `html*()` in PHP, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar issue I found an unnecessary call to `utf8_encode()` that was affecting my PHP output. Removing this call resolved the issue.